# Meteor list all users based on location

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform

I'm a Meteor newbie, and could you guide me:

I need to list all nearest users based on the location search input by user, Right now I'm using [Meteor-autoform](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform) package by Aldeed and 
[yogiben:autoform-map](https://github.com/yogiben/meteor-autoform-map) to get the user's location, but I'm not sure how to use the user's geolocation, once fetched and to dynamically resort the collection.

Comment: What you are looking for is [geo-spacial query](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query-geospatial/).

Comment: Thank you, I will go through that.